# Is there a way to display GIFs in Winforms without having them saved on the system?

Tags: c#, winforms, imagemagick

I'm currently creating a program that takes an input GIF, places text on it, and outputs it as a new GIF using the ImageMagick library. My program is perfectly operational when the output GIF is saved somewhere on the computer first and then displayed in a PictureBox by grabbing it from that directory, but is there a way to skip writing it onto disk and instead place the output GIF directly into a PictureBox after it is programmatically created?

I started by trying to have `displayPicturebox` directly display the ImageMagick `collection` variable (which theoretically is my GIF already assembled), but it wouldn't let me implicitly convert from MagickImageCollection to System.Drawing.Image.

Next I tried putting all my processed frames into a Memory Stream in GIF format and converting the Memory Stream to a Bitmap in order to be accepted by `displayPicturebox`, but this only displays a still image of the first frame and nothing else.

```
// Assume 'collection' is a collection of 10 frames to be turned into a GIF.
MagickImageCollection collection = new MagickImageCollection();

var memStream = new MemoryStream();

// Writes all frames onto memStream in GIF format...?
collection.Write(memStream, MagickFormat.Gif);

memStream.Position = 0;

var bitmap = Image.FromStream(memStream);

displayPicturebox.Image = new Bitmap(bitmap);
```

I have read that it is possible for Bitmaps to be animated, so I was wondering if there was a way to make this work or if the GIF has to be saved on disk first.

Comment: Not this: `displayPicturebox.Image = new Bitmap(bitmap);`, won't work, better `displayPicturebox.Image = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(memStream.ToArray())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you just need to assign the bitmap to the PictureBox, try this:

```
displayPicturebox.Image = bitmap;
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I glossed over this... I tried this earlier but I think due to some memory issues I was having, I was getting exceptions. I changed the line of code and it worked perfect, thanks.